# Router WAN speed limitation

Tags: router, internet, wireless-router

I intend to buy a new router, [this one](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-9_TL-WR841N.html) in particular.

It says, it supports *802.11n* protocol, so it could allow the transfer speed up to **300 Mbps** *between wireless devices*.

Strangely, the WAN speed is limited to **10/100 Mbps**.

*Obviously*, I intend to use the Internet through Wifi, but if the device can support only 100Mpbs *on wire* and the Internet is coming through a *wire* from the ISP (the ISP provides 500Mbps), I guess, the incoming Internet speed will be limited to 100Mbps.

Am I correct?

Comment: Short Answer : Yes

Comment: I was afraid so :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that the WAN facing speed will inherently limit your access here. However 100Mbit **wired** is likely to be significantly faster than 300Bbit **wireless**, so do not worry about it.

Just to explain that a bit. Modern wired Ethernet is point to point. Each device will get full speed. Wireless is a shared medium and has significantly more overhead. That means that it you place your computer right next to the router and if you are lucky then you may get up to 300Mbit though the air (minus overhead for useful data transfer).  If you move further away then wireless speed will drop significantly. Also, if you use two wireless devices at the same time. (e.g. two computers downloading something from a fileserver) then both will share those 300Mbit, effectively halfbinf useful speed.  (Mind you, if both are using the network, not just if present on it).

Comment: I don't intend to use in _wired_ mode. I need to make it as fast as it can be in _wireless mode_ to use the _500 Mbps_ speed that comes in. So I need to choose a way more expensive router for that...

Comment: @Nestor Then you want 11ac. Depending on local regulations, its range may be abysmally short, however.

Comment: Or a wired connection. Gigabit wired is cheap and often already build into motherboard. Or use wireless on a laptop and plug in a cable when downloading legal content via torrents. :)